# Why GetResponseStream() hangs in this code? How to debug it?

Tags: c#, http

Run this code inside a very simple Console application:

```
try
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create("some url here") as HttpWebRequest;
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("some JSON string here");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Host = "some host here";
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    request.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    request.Headers.Add("Origin", "some host here");
    request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    request.UserAgent =
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36";
    request.Accept = "*/*";
    request.Referer = "host here";
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
    using (Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
         newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    var result = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

Why `request.GetRequestStream()` hangs?

Comment: Just a point - why are you not being safe and using `request.ContentLength = bytes.Length`, rather than assuming 25?

Comment: Good point, updated (that was a test code)

Comment: Have you verified that your server is receiving the data? Have you verified that the server thinks it is responding? GetResponseStream should timeout when the socket times out. Does this happen?

Comment: yes i get timeout exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line `request.Host = "some host here";` from your code. It must solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

GetRequestStream of the HttpWebRequest ensures that the connection to the remote endpoint is open and that the headers are sent, before returning and allowing you to write content. If the method hangs, that likely means a network issue.

MSDN states the following:

> This member outputs trace information when you enable network tracing
>   in your application. For more information, see Network Tracing.

For debugging, you can use both network tracing ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyb3xww8.aspx ) as well as a packet sniffer like wireshark.

Comment: With filder i can post this request